# Align dataframe by row dates

Tags: pandas

The df below has a series of columns that starts with a date column followed by value columns.

I would like to align all rows on the same data.  The problem: not all columns have the same dates (some dates are missing) - see highlights in yellow.  How can I realign this df so that all series are aligned to the same dates, and empty values are included when no date exist for a particular series.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is code to split sub-df and after then join these.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

# split df into sub-df


df1 = df[['DATE','Y','Y1D', 'Y5D', 'Y20D']].rename(columns={'DATE' : 'NEWDATE'})
df2 = df[['DATE_CITI', 'CITI_INDEX','DATE_GLOBAL' , 'GLOBALINDEX']].rename(columns={'DATE_CITI' : 'NEWDATE'})
df3 = df[['DATE_HIGHYIELD', 'HIGHYIELDINDEX']].rename(columns={'DATE_HIGHYIELD' : 'NEWDATE'})




mergedata = df1.merge(df2,on='NEWDATE', how ='outer').merge(df3,on='NEWDATE', how ='outer')
```